# Facebook iOS SDK - Checking for Incoming Requests without Going Through the Facebook App?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, request

I have implemented the ability to receive facebook requests in iOS through deep linking. But it seems like to get the request, the user has to tap on the request in the Facebook app, which then opens my application.

This works, but I don't want to go through the Facebook app. I would like the app to be able to poll (or be notified) for incoming requests so that I can display them in a custom inbox. Just like Candy Crush or just about any other mobile game with an inbox.

Is this possible with the Facebook SDK, or are these apps implementing their own custom messaging system? And if so, how is it done? I can't find any facebook example code that demonstrates how to implement this flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple. Just send a request to 
https://graph.facebook.com/me/apprequests